# Global custom NavigationControl in Maui

Tags: xaml, navigation, controls, maui

I'm creating a Maui app where i want to have a custom navigationcontrol (no Tabbar) on the bottom of the screen (similar to a BottomNavigationView on Android). It should be similar to the Titleview of a Navigationpage in that it doesn't change when a Page is pushed or removed from the navigationstack. Is there any control like this in Maui?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: There is not much options aside from creating a ContentView and adding it in each of the tabs page

Comment: Perhaps it isn't clear: what @Poulpynator suggests might be fine for your needs. Project / Add Item / `ContentView`. This defines a c# class and xaml, that you could add to all your pages. Just like any other UI control. You have to manually add it in each page, e.g. `<mynamespace:mynavcontrol ... />`. But that is not hard.

Comment: You can try to implement the method on a specific platform, and then call it in Maui. Refer to the official documentation: [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0)