# How to use platformspecific controls in Maui

Tags: android, ios, maui, platform

Previously I asked if there was any way to have a [global custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510186/global-custom-navigationcontrol-in-maui) in Maui. Basically I'm trying to create a custom navigationbar for my app. And I searched for a way to not have to create and use a custom control on every page and instead create one that is visible globally (like the titleview in a NavigationPage). As it turns out, this is not possible. My idea now would be to use platformspecific code and use the native Bottomnavigation control on IOS and Android. How could I do this?
I've informed myself about Handlers but I'm not sure if it is the right approach for my problem.

Comment: That will be a LOT of work, just to avoid adding one line of xaml to each of your pages!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handlers or you can try to implement the method on a specific platform, and then call it in Maui.

There are two ways to call platform code in Maui, you can use conditional compilation or use partial class and partial method to call platform code from cross-platform code.

**Conditional compilation:**

```
public class ConditionalDemo
{
   public void TestMethod()
        {
#if ANDROID
            //your Android code
#elif IOS
            //your iOS code
#endif
        }
}
```

Then, you can create an instance of the object by calling:

```
ConditionalDemo conditional= new ConditionalDemo();
conditional.TestMethod();
```

**Partial classes and methods:**

1.Define the cross-platform API as a partial class that defines partial method signatures for any operations you want to invoke on each platform.

2.Implement the cross-platform API per platform, by defining the same partial class and the same partial method signatures, while also providing the method implementations.

3.Invoke the cross-platform API by creating an instance of the partial class and invoking its methods as required.

For more details, you can refer to the official documentation:

[Invoke platform code | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0)

[Create a custom control using handlers | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the above you can use conditional styling too.

```
<Entry>
    <Entry.Style>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Style">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" />
            <On Platform="WinUI" Value="{StaticResource WinUIEntryStyle}" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Entry.Style>
</Entry>
```